# Activity.Current is null in Azure function with BlobTrigger

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I have an Azure function(V3) that uses BlobTrigger binding and written in C#.

In order to add custom properties in Application Insights RequestTelemetry for it using

```
        Activity.Current?.AddTag("TraceId", traceId);
```

I need to access the `Activity.Current` based on the suggestion from this [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68853729/add-custom-properties-for-requesttelemetry-of-the-azure-function-v3-binding-to). However, it didn't work due to `Activity.Current is NULL`.

My package configuration looks like as follow:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.9.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" Version="2.14.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" Version="5.0.0-beta.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging.ApplicationInsights" Version="3.0.14" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="SixLabors.ImageSharp" Version="1.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" Version="5.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

And my function looks like as follow:

```
        [FunctionName("Create-Thumbnail")]
        public async Task CreateThumbnail([BlobTrigger("input/{name}",  Source = BlobTriggerSource.EventGrid, Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] Stream image,
            IDictionary<string,string> metadata,
            string name,
            ILogger log,
            ExecutionContext context)
        {         
            Activity.Current?.AddTag("TraceId", traceId);
        }
```

I have been doing research for whole day but failed to find any solution. Does anyone know what could be the issue?

Comment: Can you try creating a new Activity (you can also initialize it with a proper traceId - it should be in context)? Also, if you'd like it to appear on your Request telemetry then I think you also will need to add a TelemetryInitializer which will copy over tags from Activity.

Comment: Hi, I have created new Activity but it doesn't seem to work. Nothing has changed after this addition.

Comment: Have you created and registered TelemetryInitializer? Please refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59404790/3646920

Comment: Yes. I have done that and then tried both creating new Activity or using Activity.Current. And it didn't add anything new in the Application insights

Comment: Can you please update your question with these steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/7278), I manage to get it work after downgrading System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource to to version 4.6

```
<PackageReference Include="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" Version="4.6.0" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Currently it can be working in HTTP Trigger Functions that were ending up in the Custom Properties of Requests in application insights are no longer. Refer [here](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/562#issuecomment-891274333)

The same Activity.Current value is null issue available in github [Azure Function host](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/7278) & [Application Insights](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/562)

The Application Insights .NET SDK uses `DiagnosticSource` [(DiagnosticSourceUsersGuide)](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource/src/DiagnosticSourceUsersGuide.md) and `Activity` [(ActivityUserGuide)](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource/src/ActivityUserGuide.md) steps to collect and correlate telemetry.

Please open an issue in the Functions repo [link here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk).

Comment: Hi, a little bit confused by your answer. Do you mean it is not possible to use Activity.Current to access current RequestTelemetry right now in a function with non-HTTP trigger?

Comment: Hi @codigube, Yes it is not possible in non-http trigger. Only possible in Http-trigger but achieving this we need to downgrade Microsoft.ApplicationInsights to 3.0.14. The bug(Activity.Current is null) still available in GitHub.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Do you know if there is anyway to access the RequestTelemetry in non-http trigger since I want to add custom property to RequestTelemetry for the function.

Comment: Currently not possible please open an issue in Function Repo https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk